# "Lost" code changes - what does this mean?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I am investigating a code reversion issue. I am a bit new to Git and am having trouble understanding what I am seeing. I have picked a "signature" change and am trying to understand what happened to the file since the change.

1) I can see the change as a commit to a branch, however this only shows up in "git log --follow " and does not show up as a change in "gitk " but does if I use "gitk --all ".

2) When viewing the latest version of the file in Atlassian Stash or the local file system, the changes are not evident in the file. However the latest change in Atlassian Stash and gitk that was committed on the file does have the expected changes in it. So I can select the commit in both gitk and Stash and see the change being made, but when Viewing the file content the changes are not there.

3) "git log --follow " does not indicate any changes to the file since the expected change was made, and neither does "git whatchanged ".

This problem is not isolated to this file - about a weeks worth of changes have the same symptoms - changes were made and I can see them in Stash and using git log, but the latest copy of the files obtained through Atlassian Stash or git pull do not incorporate the changes.

What could have happened to generate this set of symptoms ? I assume that any change to a file (either through a deliberate commit, or through errant merging) would always show up in the log files and on Atlassian Stash, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you are talking about *stash* do you actually mean [*git stash*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) because the way you phrased it makes it possible that you mean something else. Maybe the index?

Comment: Sorry - to be clear I am talking about Atlassian Stash. I've edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: please, add screenshots of `git log --follow`, gitk --all`, Atlassian Stash history and latest version of the file that you refer to. Might be, changes are recorded on the wrong branch or overridden by a merge commit that you don't understand.

Comment: @Isantipov I'm afraid I wont be able to do this, not only because the branch tree is almost unintelligibly complex, but also because it would get me in trouble. However, when you talk of "being overridden by a merge commit" would that not be recoreded as a commit on the file history ?

Comment: @PhillipH , you can blur sensitive information or just re-draw commit history using ASCII art. Yes, merge commit is visible in the history but it sounds like you may be overlooking it due to "complex branch structure"

Comment: @Istanipov - sorry if I'm sounding negative, I realise you are trying to help, but I can't even understand the merge history to simplify it - I was hoping just looking at the file history would tell me all the times it had changed, however that change occured. The branch structure seems to be 20 branches deep in places with many terminals and merges both back and forward (if I'm interpreting it right). Hopefully someone can tell me "obvious symptom of a 'git push --force'" or some other common mis-use. :-\

Comment: @PhillipH , I think the info, provided is not sufficient to understand what's going on. My only guess is that you're misunderstanding branches and the changes you've lost are recorded on the wrong branch.